# finding a function with predetermined $f^{(n)}$s at $0$ and $1$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $a_n,b_n$ be 2 arbitrary sequences of real numbers. Is there any $C^\infty$ function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for any $n$:
$$f^{(n)}(0)=a_n,\quad f^{(n)}(1)=b_n$$

Comment: A complex analytic function is entirely determined by all its derivatives in a point. Therefore the sequences $\{a_n\}_n$ and $\{b_n\}_n$ depend mutually one on the other in case $f$ is required to be analytic.

Comment: In the case of $C^\infty$-functions, the $a_n$ and $b_n$ can be chosen completely independently, because you can glue $C^\infty$-functions together with a *partition of unity*. So your question is reduced to the problem of finding $f$ such that $f^{(n)}(0)=a_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: For analytic functions the answer is no in general, no matter whether they are complex or real valued.

Comment: Real or complex analytic, the answer is no. Take $a_n=(n!)^2$ and think about the radius of convergence of $\sum \frac{a_n}{n!}x^n$.

Comment: $C^\infty$ need not be analytic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For smooth functions, this is a version of [Whitney's extension theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Whitney_extension_theorem).

For analytic functions, the answer is 'no' as already stated in the comments. It's not even true for one point.

Comment: Adding a bit to the last point on analytic functions, if we ignore $(b_n)$, a necessary but insufficient condition is $\limsup\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}<\infty$.  A sufficient but unnecessary condition is $\limsup\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=0$, if we're only talking about real analytic functions.  In the complex analytic case where $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ is entire, the last condition would also be necessary.

Comment: I don't understand what Whitney says. So such $C^\infty$ function exists?!

Comment: @CutieKrait: Yes.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially a duplicate of

[Order of growth of derivatives at given x](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352392/)

For a cutoff function $g(x)$ equal to $1$ near $0$ and vanishing outside $(-1/2,1/2)$, take $\sum (\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n g(nx) + \frac{b_n}{n!}(x-1)^n g(n(x-1))$.