# Order of growth of derivatives at given x

Tags: derivatives, asymptotics

Is there such an $f$ smooth function and $x\in D_f$, so that the sequence $f(x), f'(x), f''(x), ...$ grows faster than exponential?

Can it grow at a factorial rate or faster?

Comment: You mean to say "*the sequence*". For example, $(1,2,4,8,\ldots)$ is a geometric *sequence* while $1+2+4+8+\cdots$ is a geometric *series*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a single point $x$, it can be arranged that $f^{(n)}(x)=d_n$ for an arbitrary sequence $d_n$.

Comment: And how do you do that? Say I would like $d_n=n!$ at $x=0$, can you show me such a function?

Comment: Well, it is part of the ideas like "bump function" and gluing of smooth functions, where you have total freedom to do anything locally.  You can take the sum of a series $\sum d_n \frac{x^n}{n!} g(nx)$ where $g(x)$ is $1$ near $0$, zero for $|x| \geq 1$, and infinitely differentiable.

Comment: After some heavy calculation I found that $f=\frac{1}{1-x}$ matches my needs. Didn't think it would be that simple :)

Comment: Ah!  Yes, if the series converges, then the same sum without the $g(nx)$ will work in some neighborhood of zero.  But then factorial growth is the fastest you can do.